# Definition of Finite Projective Plane clarification

Tags: combinatorics, projective-geometry

[image]

---

---

I do not understand part iii. Why can't there be four collinear points?

The Fano plane is an example of a $3$-uniform configuration. What about configurations that are $4$-uniform? You must have $4$ points on one line.

Comment: iii does not say that there can't be four collinear points: it says that there are four points such that no subset of three of them is contained in a line. In other words, a cuadrangle.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez If we have points $a,b,c,d$ on a line, then we have $3$ of them on a line. I don't understand.

Comment: iii does not say that «every four points blah» it says «there exist four points such that blah».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't see the difference. "There are four points no three of which lie on a line." There are four points: $a,b,c,d$; no three of which lie on a line: so, we cannot have $a,b,c$ on a line?

Comment: Do you see that there is a differnce between «There is a user of this site whose name is Mariano» and «All users of this site are named Mariano.»

Comment: In any case, your problem is not quite with the geometry but with logic :-|

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can you provide an example in an answer?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Clarifying the definition. I am not trying to answer a question. I am just asking for clarification of the definition. I understand you are trying to show me the difference, but you must understand that you are currently not helping.

Comment: I don't think I can help you. I have already explained what iii means, and Avi has also done it. I don't know what more I can do. And you still have not answered my question: do you understand that there is a difference between «There is a user named Mariano» and «All users are named Mariano».

Comment: Obviously I know the difference in your question. Thanks for the help though and the belittlement.

Comment: The definition says $\textit{there exist}$ four points such that no three of them are on a line. It does not say $\textit{for any}$ four points, no three of them are on a line.

Comment: I don't know where you see belittlement. In any case, in this site we prefer not to delete questions which have answers.

Comment: Now, if you see the difference between my two statements, can you see that they are in the same relation as the statements «all quadruples (A,B,C,D) of points have the property that none of the sets {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,C,D}, {B,C,D} are contained in a line» and «there is a quadruple (A,B,C,D) of points which has the property that none of the sets {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,C,D}, {B,C,D} are contained in a line»? Having said that, I have to confess that whatever motivation I had to help you, you managed to make it go away.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions: Users can delete their own questions if the question:

-has zero answers
-only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes. The answer has no upvotes. -- Thus, I can delete. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the technically imposed rule. In this site, however, we prefer not to disparage the evident effort put by answerers, even if no one has yet upvoted their answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I understand you are "trying" to help by making a generality with some other statement, but once again, it is not helping. Maybe you should try a different tactic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXAMPLE:**

Consider the Fano Plane: [image]

Condition (iii) of the definition says: *there are four points no three of which lie on a line*.

Now, points $1,2,3$ do lie on a line, however, consider the points $2,3,6,7$. At most two of these points lie on a line. No three of the points  $2,3,6,7$ lie on a line. Thus, condition (iii) is satisfied.

Another example would be the points $1,2,4,7$.

Answer (score 2):

There can be four points on a line. All this says is that there exist four distinct points no three of which are collinear. There might also be other points.

**EDIT:** Let's try thinking of this algorithmically:

Let $P$ be the set of points.

**Step 0.** Make a list of all 4-element subsets of $P$. Label them $S_1, S_2,S_3,\ldots,S_n$ (it's a finite list since $P$ is finite).

**Step 1.** Look at $S_1$. This consists of four points. If no three of these four points are collinear, then we win, i.e. property iii holds.

**Step 2.** Otherwise, look at $S_2$. This consists of four points. If no three of these four points are collinear, then we win, i.e. property iii holds.

**Step 3.** Otherwise, look at $S_3$. This consists of four points. If no three of these four points are collinear, then we win, i.e. property iii holds.

...

**Step n.** Otherwise, look at $S_n$. This consists of four points. If no three of these four points are collinear, then we win, i.e. property iii holds.

**Step n+1.** Otherwise, we lose, i.e. property iii fails.

Comment: I am still not understanding. Can you please explain more? If there are four points on a line, then four are collinear.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "there exist points $A,B,C,D$ such that no three of $A,B,C,D$  are collinear" and "for all points $A,B,C,D$, no three of $A,B,C,D$  are collinear"?

Comment: So, we can have four points on a line, but we cannot have three of them on a line? That does not make sense.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?